# Devolverme el id del personal del usuario que a iniciado sesión - laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

Como le hago para que me devuelva el id del personal que está en mi tabla personal  del usuario que a iniciado sesión, donde el id del usuario esta en la tabla del personal.

Hasta el momento solo me ha obtenido el id del usuario que a iniciado sesión,mediante auth()->user()->ID, pero lo que quisiera es que me devuelva es el ID del personal que inicio sesión.

En este fragmento de código prácticamente estoy devolviendo todas las asistencias del personal=id_personal, pero en este caso me devuelve el id del usuario mediante el metodo auth()->user()->id, asignándole este valor al 'id_personal'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Base datos Tabla personal y tabla Users:

[image: Base datos Tabla personal y tabla Users]

Mis modelos:
Modelo Personal

```html
class Personal extends Model{
public function asistencias(){
        return $this->hasMany(Asistencia::class,'id');
    }
 public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id_user');
    }
}
```

Modelo Asistencia:

```html
class Asistencia extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    
    public function personals(){
    
        return $this->belongsTo(Personal::class,'id_personal');

    }

}
```

```html
class User extends Authenticatable
{
public function personals(){
    
      return $this->hasMany(Personal::class,'id');


    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Lo siento pero tu pregunta carece de un [example] y va a ser muy dificil ayudarte. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender como funciona este sitio y como deben ser las preguntas para ser consideradas por la comunidad y podamos ayudarte mejor. En tu pregunta, aparte que no vemos más allá de lo que muestras, no se entiende lo que estas diciendo. Piensa que nosotros no estamos viendo lo que tu ves y nos lo tienes que explicar mejor para entenderlo. Gracias!

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor deberias poner la estructura de la tabla `personal` para poder ver el nombre de los campos y saber en cual se está guardando el id del usuario, para luego poder usarlo en el `where` de una consulta, con ese campo y el valor que ya tienes del id de usuario, en la tabla personal.

Comment: Hola!!! ya adjunte mi base de datos

Comment: En PHP+SQL puro la consulta seria esta: `$q = 'SELECT id FROM personals WHERE id_user="'.auth()->user()->id.'"';`  pero en laravel ni idea, aun nunca lo he usado, y tampoco se los constructores ni modelos que estas usando, pero espero que te sirva de referencia para algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! por tu ayuda @masterguru, si me servirá de mucho.

Comment: Una pregunta, vista la respuesta que te han dado, tengo una duda... la relación entre la tabla users y la tabla personals es de 1 a muchos? Es decir, ¿puede haber varios registros en personals que usen el mismo id de user?  Lo digo porque entonces mi consulta sigue siendo válida, pero te saldrá más de una coincidencia. En caso contrario, es decir, si solo puede haber un registro en personals  que coincida con el id de usuario, entonces dudo que la respuesta que te han dado sea del todo precisa.

Comment: Exacto el id del user lo tengo almacenada en la tabla personal @masterguru tal como se puede ver en las imagenes.

Answer (score 1):

Solución a mi duda:

```
 public function index(){        
  
 $id = Personal::select('id')->where('id_user','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
    
  $asistencias = Asistencia::where('id_personal', $id[0]->id)->get();
    

  return view('asistencia.index',compact('asistencias','id'));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para tu clase **Personals** debes añadir la relacion de **Eloquent** de la siguiente manera:

(1 User - N Personals)

---

```
    class Personals extends Model
    {
//.....

      public function user(){

         return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_user');
      }
//.....
    }
```

Y en tu clase **User** :

```
class User extends Model
{

//.....
    public function personals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Personals::class,'id_user');
    }
//.....
}
```

> Para obtener todos los **Personals del usuario logeado**

```
$user = Auth::user();
$personals = $user->personals;
```

PD: Revisa los nombres que he puesto a las clases ya que igual no se llaman asi exactamente, pero esa es la idea. Te debe de valer.